# ProLiant ML350 Gen9 SATA Questions

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, sata

Im a newbie with the "real" server-world, previously I've used ordinary pc's for servers but got my hands on a ML350 Gen9 recently and decided to have a go.

Now to my questions.

1, How large SATA drives can the motherboard handle? Thinking of getting 2x Seagate Exos 16TB and doing Raid1 for secure storage.

2, Will the ML350 "accept" the non-HP certified discs and not send the fans into max-speed?

Thanks in advance

//Anders

Comment: Throw away that server. It's ancient, power hungry and end of life. And read the manual - https://www.hpe.com/psnow/doc/c04346270.html?jumpid=in_lit-psnow-red. It probably depends on the controller.

Answer (score 1):

The HP documentation specifies a maximum of 12 TB. That is based on the most recent QuickSpecs, which were *last* published five years ago on April 2018.

The maximum storage is 288 TB, in a 24 x 12 TB drive configuration.

If you need to know if any disk will work in an HP ProLiant Server, you will need to acquire one and insert it and test it. There isn't a matrix that shows all disks that work with HP ProLiant servers.

https://www.hpe.com/psnow/doc/c04375628.pdf?jumpid=in_lit-psnow-getpdf

Comment: OK, thank you for your answer Greg. I'll dig deeper into it. Have a nive day :)

Answer (score 0):

- The HPE ProLiant ML350 Gen9 server motherboard supports up to 8 SATA drives with a maximum storage capacity of 10 TB each, for a total of 80 TB. However, the server also supports SAS and NVMe drives, which can offer higher performance and larger storage capacities. So, you should check the server's storage controller and backplane to see if they support SAS and NVMe drives.

Regarding the specific Seagate Exos 16TB SATA drives you are considering, you should check the server's QuickSpecs or consult with HPE support to confirm their compatibility with your server.

- The HPE ProLiant ML350 Gen9 server should accept non-HP certified drives, but there may be some limitations or risks. Non-certified drives may not be fully compatible with the server's firmware, which could result in lower performance or stability issues. Additionally, HPE may not provide support for issues related to non-certified drives.

Regarding the server's fans, the server's fan speed is typically determined by the temperature of the server's components, not the type of drives used. If the non-certified drives run hotter than certified drives, the server's fans may spin faster to keep the server cool. So, you should monitor the server's temperature and fan speed to ensure that the non-certified drives are not causing any overheating issues.You may also find more info [here](https://hpe.to/6608ObeCr).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, very appreciated. I'm probarly going to put these discs in an external NAS instead, and use them over gigabit network. Easier, and works for what I want to use them for